# Using commas to initialize/set multiple variables, without "var"?

Tags: javascript

I've seen many examples of:

```
var foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = 3;
```

But, can I do the same without `var`? Example:

```
// Declare at top of block for readability's sake:
var foo, bar, baz;
// ... stuff here ...
// Later in script, I finally get around to initializing above vars:
foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = 3; // Is using commas without var legal?
```

In other words, is it legal in javascript to have a line where I initialize/set multiple vars without the `var` keyword? I have not been able to find any definitive documentation on whether or not this is allowed and/or well supported.

The alternative would be:

```
foo = 1; bar = 2; baz = 3;
```

---

Here's the real world situation that prompted my question:

```
for (var i = 0, l = haystack.length; i < l; i++) { ... }
```

... I'd like to move the varible delcaration inside the `for` loop to the top level of the parent block, like:

```
var i, l;

// ... stuff here ...

for (i = 0, l = haystack.length; i < l; i++) { ... }
```

... But I've only ever used the commas when using `var` at the beginning of the statement. Is the above legal(?), or should it be:

```
var i, l;

// ... stuff here ...

for (i = 0; l = haystack.length; i < l; i++) { ... }
```

(Note the added semicolon.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript you can separate expressions by commas and they will execute left to right, returning the value of the far right expression

So yes you can do this in general and the following is legal syntax.

```
for (i = 0, l = haystack.length; i < l; i++) { ... }
```

See more about the comma operator here: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: Thanks Ben! Would there be anything wrong with using a semicolon in the `for` loop after the `i = 0` (instead of a comma)? Do you normally use commas for setting multiple vars (when not using the `var` keyword), or do you prefer semicolons?

Comment: I don't believe that would work within the for loop.  You can see the specs for those loops here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for It looks like you can only have 3 statements. Adding an extra would not be valid syntax.

Comment: Ah, to answer my own question, it looks like the comma is preferred when in the context of a `for` loop: `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])`. Found via [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) as well. I thought this was also good to know: "The result of [the initialization] expression is discarded".